# Strange order of line insertion

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that inserts a line in a table. This table has an auto incremented `int` primary key and a `datetime2` column named `CreationDate`. I am calling it in a for loop via my C# code, and the loop is inside a transaction scope.

I run the program twice, first time with a for loop that turned 6 times and second time with a for loop that turned 2 times. When I executed this select on sql server I got a strange result

```
SELECT TOP 8 
    RequestId, CreationDate 
FROM 
    PickupRequest  
ORDER BY 
    CreationDate DESC
```

[image]

What I didn't get is the order of insertion: for example the line with Id=58001 has to be inserted after that with Id=58002 but this is not the case. Is that because I put my loop in a transaction scoope? or the precision in the datetime2 is not enough?

Comment: "but this is not the case" I see no indication of your statement being true. The numbers are going up as time goes up. You have no single number where the number goes up but time is less than the number before.

Comment: Why would 58001 be inserted after 58002?

Comment: this is correct, the primary key value is correct, look at your query you order the result by creation date DESCENDING, so it's expected that the values from second loop will go first since they are inserted after the execution of first loop.

Comment: You told it to order by CreationDate in your select. It's doing exactly that, and nothing more. If you want the IDs to ascend as well, then change to `ORDER BY CreationDate DESC, RequestID DESC`. Or remove the `DESC`s if you want it to go up. This is purely a viewing issue.

Comment: I think what he/she mean is that the time for 58002 should be later then 58001 in milliseconds. Or if the precision is only on seconds. Otherwise 58002 should have come before 58001 unless they were inserted on the exact same ms.

Comment: since 58001 and 58002 have the same time - there is a guess of sql that you want to order the Id too.

it defaults to ascending - change the query to
    SELECT TOP 8 RequestId, CreationDate FROM PickupRequest  ORDER BY CreationDate DESC, RequestId DESC

Comment: @FSDaniel But if the time is the same (as it is), there's no guarantee on sort order of matching elements. The server will throw them out as is most convenient.

Comment: @TabAlleman  I forgot to mention that the creationdate is obtained with GETDATE(). From this display CreationDate(requestId=58001) > CreationDate(requestId=58002) so I deduced that the line with Id = 58001 is inserted in the second place

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot and Tom, i think both the writer and myself understands why the order is as it is. I just tried to clarify what i think the writer meant. Why is it not using ms to sort better or is that lost due to precision (as mentioned in the question) or is because of the use of a transaction that everything gets the same time?

Comment: @AnotherGeek, you output shows that `CreationDate(requestId=58001) = CreationDate(requestId=58002)`, as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a question of **speed** and **statement scope** as well...

Try this:

--This will create a `@numbers` table with 1 mio numbers:

```
DECLARE  @numbers TABLE(Nbr BIGINT);
WITH N(N) AS
(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1)
,MoreN(N) AS
(SELECT 1 FROM N AS N1 CROSS JOIN N AS N2 CROSS JOIN N AS N3 CROSS JOIN N AS N4 CROSS JOIN N AS N5 CROSS JOIN N AS N6)
INSERT INTO @numbers(Nbr) 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM MoreN;
```

--This is a dummy table for inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE Dummy(ID INT IDENTITY,CreationDate DATETIME);
```

--Play around with the value for `@Count`. You can insert 1 mio rows in one go. Although this runs a while, all will have the same datetime value:

--Use a small number here **and** below, still the same time value

--Use a big count here and a small below will show a slightly later value for the second insert

```
DECLARE @Count INT = 1000;
INSERT INTO Dummy (CreationDate)
SELECT GETDATE()
FROM (SELECT TOP(@Count) 1 FROM @numbers) AS X(Y);
```

--A second insert

```
SET @Count = 10;
INSERT INTO Dummy (CreationDate)
SELECT GETDATE()
FROM (SELECT TOP(@Count) 1 FROM @numbers) AS X(Y);

SELECT * FROM Dummy;
```

--Clean up

```
GO
DROP TABLE Dummy;
```

Answer (score 2):

You did your insertions pretty fast so the actual `CreationDate` values inserted in one program run had the same values. In case you're using `datetime` type, all the insertions may well occur in one millisecond. So `ORDER BY CreationDate DESC` by itself does not guarantee the select order to be that of insertion.

To get the desired order you need to sort by the `RequestId` as well:

```
SELECT TOP 8 RequestId, CreationDate 
FROM PickupRequest
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC, RequestId DESC
```